# How to refresh the UI view from subview custom cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

**MY XIB DESIGN**

[image]

I have design screen like this, In run time I have screen like

[image]

In this have a view with name and plus and minus button, In run time I have name 1, name 2 and name 3 etc . When I click plus button increase the value from 1 to ... and show it count label, then when I click the minus button I wan decrease the count label value.

My click event code in Custom cell class,

```
_(IBAction)click:sender
{
    NSUInteger no =2;
    second-class *sc = [[secondclass alloc] init];
    [sc numberOfItem:no];
}
```

When I click the button in custom cell, I want to change the **Count label value** in Main class, My main class coding is

```
-(void)nuberofitem:no
{
    NSLog(@"number : %d",no); //It shows correct value
    localtextbox.text = no;

    NSLog(@"text box value : %@", localtextbox.text); //But in  label it shows null value
}
```

not able to change the **count label value** I don't know how to do this thing can any know help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The button (custom or otherwise) shouldn't be telling the rest of the application anything other than "I was tapped!".

Set the button up so that it's target is your view controller and it's action is some appropriate method in the view controller. Tapping the button will then trigger the action in the view controller. Being part of the view controller, the action should be able to add a row to the table and also update the value in the label.

The button itself shouldn't know anything about the label, the table, or anything else.

Comment: Is it possible to do this thing.

Comment: @Yugesh I'm not sure I follow you. It's certainly possible to use a button to change the number of rows in a table, but again, the code that does the actual changing should be part of the controller, not the button. Putting it in the button means that the button has to know a lot about the rest of the app.

Comment: Sorry,i can't able to understand your answer.(my question is clear for you or not)